# Constructing Triangles given some parameters

Tags: geometry

In my maths assignment, it says:

1. Construct a triangle with perimeter $115$ mm, altitude $70$ mm and vertical angle $45^\circ$.
2. Constructing a triangle with altitude $76$ mm and base angles $60$ and $45$ degrees.
3. Construct an isosceles triangle given $135$ mm as perimeter and altitude as $55$ mm.

I  am very confused on what to do from the beginning. How do I construct such Triangles?

Comment: The second looks like the easiest. Can you see how to get the sides? [Do you know some basic formulae like opposite/hypotenuse = sine?]

Comment: I know how, but the angles and altitude are giving me headaches...

Comment: If I use 45°for b, 60° will not fit, because of the altitude

Comment: SOHCAHTOA right?

Comment: I don't see the headaches for 2. Triangle $ABC$, So assume $\angle B=45^\circ,\angle C=60^\circ$ and the altitude is $AD$. What is $AB$ in terms of $\angle B$ and $AD$?

Comment: In (2) you draw the altitude. Then angles $90-60=30$ and $90-45=45$ on each side at one of its end points. Then draw a perpendicular at the other end point of the altitude.

Comment: My problem is with (1).  How can the perimeter of a teiangle beess than twice an altitude?  Need to check problem statement.

Comment: For (3) you have that if $a$ is the side and $b$ is half of the base, then $b^2+55^2=a^2$. Also $a+b=135/2$. From this you get that $a-b=\frac{2\cdot 55^2}{135}$. So, $a=\frac{135/2+\frac{2\cdot 55^2}{135}}{2}$ and $b=\frac{135/2-\frac{2\cdot 55^2}{135}}{2}$.

Comment: In (1) the perimeter is larger than twice the altitude, when this is inside the triangle. Since 115<2\cdot 70 it must be that the altitude is outside.

Comment: @oscarrascal the perimeter should also be larger than twice the altitude when the altutude is outside the triangle, too.  Each leg to the apex must measure at least the altitude and there are two of those.  (1) as written cannot exist!

Comment: @KingRoyal What are the tools you are supposed to use to do these constructions?   Only a compass and a straight-edge?

Answer (score 0):

Call the triangle $ABC$, and the altitude $AD$.

(1) construct a triangle with perimeter length 115 and with the altitude length 70.

That is impossible. $ADB$ is a right-angled triangle, so $AB>AD$. Similarly, $AC>AD$. So the perimeter must be greater than $2AD$.

(2) construct a triangle with $\angle B=45\circ$, $\angle C=60\circ$ and $AD=76$.

We have $AB\sin\angle B=AD$, which gives us $AB$. Similarly $AC\sin\angle C=AD$, which gives us $AC$. Similarly, $AB\cos\angle B+AC\cos\angle C=BC$. So we have all the side lengths and constructing the triangle is trivial.

(3) construct a triangle with perimeter 135, $AD=55$ and $AB=AC$. Suppose $BC=x$. Then $AB=AC=\sqrt{55^2+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$. So we have perimeter $135=x+2\sqrt{55^2+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$. So we can solve for $x$ (approx 22.7) and hence get the side lengths.

Comment: Any pictures or videos on how I can construct this?

Comment: Should I use the perimeter as the base line?

Comment: @YNK Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @KingRoyal  You keep asking question after question. But, you refuses to answer question posed by people who want to help you.
I asked you a question 14 hours ago, which has gone unanswered until now. I am asking the same question again.
What are the tools you are supposed to use to do these constructions? Only a compass and a straight-edge? 
almagest's answer is completely adequate for you to do the constructions. You sound like you are afraid to put your hand to a pen to draw something.
Don't be afraid. Start doing your construction.

Comment: I don't see any questions..... I have constructed number  2 and 3, but am very confused in number one. Sorry if I am bothering anyone. It's my first time.

Comment: @KingRoyal All you can do on number 1 is to state that it is impossible and explain why. It may be a typo in the question, but there is no point in speculating.

Comment: @YNK maybe you could upvote the answer (which is CW so no benefit to me). That would clear it from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @KingRoyal I am sorry if you think I have been rude to you. My comment containing the question is there, but it is hidden. No, you are not bothering anybody. I am unable to help you unless you answer my question.

Comment: I can't see any questions sir

Comment: @KingRoyal Have you overcome your worries about the first problem?

Comment: Ok yes. A compass, protractor and ruler.

Comment: I don't think they help for the 1st problem!

Comment: I would use the perimeter as the base line for the first question, which I have completed.

Comment: How do I get 3?